# Succession of countdown timers in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I need multiple countdown timers with different periods following each other. How can I stop one and start another in the same activity and the same label.

I have this code for now:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!

    var count = Int()
    var timer = Timer()
    var timerIndex = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

var timerHasFinishedRunning: Bool = false
func update() {

    let minutes = String(count / 60)
    let seconds = String(count % 60)

    if count == 0 {


        if timerIndex == 0 { count = 12
        }
        else if timerIndex == 1 {
            count = 11
        }
        else if timerIndex == 2 {
            count = 10
        }
        else if timerIndex == 3 {
            count = 9
        }
        else {
            timer.invalidate()
            countDownLabel.text = "The timer has finished running!"
            timerHasFinishedRunning = true

        }
        if timerHasFinishedRunning == false{
            let minutes = String(count / 60)
            let seconds = String(count % 60)

            countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds

            timer.invalidate()
            timerIndex += 1
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

    }
    else {
        if timerIndex == 0{
            count -= 1
            let minutes = String(count / 60)
            let seconds = String(count % 60)
            countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        }
        else if timerIndex == 1{
            count -= 1
            let minutes = String(count / 60)
            let seconds = String(count % 60)
            countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        }
        else if timerIndex == 2{
            count -= 1
            let minutes = String(count / 60)
            let seconds = String(count % 60)
            countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        }
        else if timerIndex == 3{
            count -= 1
            let minutes = String(count / 60)
            let seconds = String(count % 60)
            countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
        }

    }

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Initial Answer:

**Replace your `update()` function to this, if you want the format to be M:S:**

```
var timerHasFinishedRunning: Bool = false


func update() {

        if count == 0{

            if timerIndex == 0{ count = 200 // or the desired value for the second timer


            }
            else if timerIndex == 1{
                count = 40 // or the desired value for the third timer
            }
            else {
            timer.invalidate()
            countDownLabel.text = "The timer has finished running!"
            timerHasFinishedRunning = true

            }
            if timerHasFinishedRunning == false{
            let minutes = String(count / 60)
            let seconds = String(count % 60)
            countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds

            timer.invalidate()
            timerIndex += 1
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
          }  

        }
        else {
            if timerIndex == 0{
                count -= 1
                let minutes = String(count / 60)
                let seconds = String(count % 60)
                countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
            }
            else if timerIndex == 1{
                count -= 1
                let minutes = String(count / 60)
                let seconds = String(count % 60)
                countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
            }
            else if timerIndex == 2{
                count -= 1
                let minutes = String(count / 60)
                let seconds = String(count % 60)
                countDownLabel.text = minutes + ":" + seconds
            }
        }
    }
```

---

### EDIT:

**Replace your code to this, and add your new values! Format: MM:SS:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var countDownLabel: UILabel!

    var count = Int()
    var timer = Timer()
    var timerIndex = 0
    var timerHasFinishedRunning: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        count = 5

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func update() {
        if count == 0{

            if timerIndex == 0{ count = 3 // or the desired value for the second timer


            }
            else if timerIndex == 1{
                count = 2 // or the desired value for the third timer
            }
            else {

                timer.invalidate()
                countDownLabel.text = "The timer has finished running!"
                timerHasFinishedRunning = true

            }
            if timerHasFinishedRunning == false{
                let minutes = Int(count / 60)
                let seconds = Int(count % 60)
                if minutes > 9{
                    if  seconds >= 10{
                        countDownLabel.text = "\(minutes)" + ":" + "\(seconds)"
                    }
                    else if seconds < 10{
                        countDownLabel.text = "\(minutes)" + ":" + "0\(seconds)"
                    }
                }
                else if minutes<=9{
                    if  seconds >= 10{
                        countDownLabel.text = "0\(minutes)" + ":" + "\(seconds)"
                    }
                    else if seconds < 10{
                        countDownLabel.text = "0\(minutes)" + ":" + "0\(seconds)"
                    }
                }

            timer.invalidate()
            timerIndex += 1
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }

        }
        else {

                count -= 1
                let minutes = Int(count / 60)
                let seconds = Int(count % 60)
                if minutes > 9{
                    if  seconds >= 10{
                    countDownLabel.text = "\(minutes)" + ":" + "\(seconds)"
                    }
                    else if seconds < 10{
                        countDownLabel.text = "\(minutes)" + ":" + "0\(seconds)"
                    }
                }
                else if minutes<=9{
                    if  seconds >= 10{
                        countDownLabel.text = "0\(minutes)" + ":" + "\(seconds)"
                    }
                    else if seconds < 10{
                        countDownLabel.text = "0\(minutes)" + ":" + "0\(seconds)"
                    }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I will update the answer once again, if I will figure out a way to fix your issue.
*Hope this helps!*

### SIMULATOR:

[image: Simulator]

Comment: And you can keep on doing this.

Comment: I have added those **`if`** statements, for you to be able to customize your function for each timer value that you have, but if the settings are the same for all three timers you can replace them and the last else statement will contain only contain 4 lines of code... Of course, it is your own choice

Comment: Please let me know if that helped you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine until the last timerIndex. Then it only displays the count value but counting does not start. I know there should be a simple solution to that. I will be grateful if you help. Thanks again

Comment: I tested it and it worked just perfectly for me. Have you added anything in the function besides my code? For some reason, it works just fine for me...

Comment: If so, share your code to me, please(if you added anything else)

Comment: Now, I have noticed the issue you were talking about! Working on it

Comment: I have updated the answer now and the issue is gone for me. Let me know if it helped you and make sure to hit that check button if so! :)))

Comment: In my case the timer still stops at 9 (see my code). I also need it to be in 00:10--00:09 format all the time. Here's the complete code

Comment: I edited it with your input. If you could help me finish the task, it would be a huge progress for my learning. Thanks

Comment: I am thinking of it! I will help you with the formatting, but I don't know if I am able to solve the others... I am thinking, please wait a couple of hours

Comment: Fixed the formatting. I'll try fix the other issue!

Comment: Let me know if it helped

Comment: @AntonPlatonov Apparently, it works just fine for me :))). After I've made the edit everything works perfectly and it doesn't crack at 9 seconds, although I used your code! If it still doesn't work for you, the problem is not the code I've provided. It whether is something from the **Debugger**, from your **Compiler**, or some other lines of code which you have added. I am going to prove it by adding a **.gif** file of the simulator. I will reexamine your code and if something appears to be the issue, I will tell you right away. That is everything I have for you so far. I'd be glad if it works

Comment: I changed the values to 2,3,2,3 to be able to take the **.gif** file which can last for no more than 15 seconds

Answer (score 0):

try this..just change according to your requirement

```
 var count = Int()
 var timer = NSTimer()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a 

  printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(100)

  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


}
 func update() {
count = 1 + count
if(count != 0) {
  printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds(count)

} else {
  timer.invalidate()
}
```

}

```
func printSecondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds:Int) -> () {
 let (h, m, s) = secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (Double(seconds))
print ("\(h) Hours, \(m) Minutes, \(s) Seconds")
```

}

```
func secondsToHoursMinutesSeconds (seconds : Double) -> (Double, Double, Double) {
let (hr,  minf) = modf (seconds / 3600)
let (min, secf) = modf (60 * minf)
return (hr, min, 60 * secf)
```

}